# Unable to connect to S3 using Interface Endpoint: Connection timeout on endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to configure a VPC environment where the ec2 instance in the private subnet has access to S3, but I've been having trouble getting it to work. If anyone can offer some guidance it would help a lot. Here's my VPC setup with 1 private and 1 public subnets:

> VPC: CIDR 20.0.0.0/24 with DNS hostnames and DNS resolution enabled

> Public Subnet: CIDR 20.0.0.0/28 with Route Table
>
> 20.0.0.0/24   local
> 0.0.0.0/0 igw-0e9c938ccf95c7365

> Private Subnet: CIDR 20.0.0.32/28 with Route Table
>
> 20.0.0.0/24   local

Each subnet has 1 ec-2 instance with roles assigned giving full S3 access. My endpoint is created with the service "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3" on my private subnet and the security group attached is default VPC security group.

When I try calling aws s3api list-buckets, I get a connection timeout. It works if I attach attach a NAT gateway to the route table, so it seems like it's not able to connect to the endpoint. Is my configuration wrong?

Comment: What are security group on the interface endpoint? Did you open port 443?

Comment: Yes it's open to all traffic. I just used the security group that is created it with the VPC.

Comment: All traffic All All sg-01b729bba81f21ae0 / default – | All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 –

Comment: I figured it out. I had Private DNS names enabled set to true. After I recreated the endpoints it's working.